# what does network speed means in vps in linux

Tags: linux

I have the VPS hosting from company and in specifaction they write

> VPS Port Speed: 100Mbit.

what is that speed , is it enough for 10 sites

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is impossible to help you with!

That simply (most likely) means that the virtual private server has a Virtual 100 Megabit per second card.

The (physical) server itself may and most likely will have a gigabit connection (or multiples) to the switch, but then, it can be limited to anything that the hosting company wants, and will be shared with everyone who has a VPS on the same server as you.

So, you may get a full 100 Meg, but this is unlikely.

Next, is it enough for 10 sites - again, not enough information! If you mean will it be enough for a site with less than 100 views a day - it can probably hold a few thousand (if not more) sites like that... If you mean will it hold a site the size of Microsoft or another multi national company - the answer will be no!

Answer (score 0):

VPS means "Virtual Private Server". As far as number of sites, that will depend on how popular those sites are. If they're the average blog, then that's probably overkill. If they're sites the size of SourceForge, that's not going to be enough.